# Autocomplete searchbar stops working after adding Google Maps Weather layer

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables, google-places-api

I had a perfect working Google Map, connecting to my Fusion Tables, with nice searchbar.
until... I added the new Google Maps Weather Layer this morning.

After that the autocomplete searchbar/Google Places stopped working.

I tried everything possible, I think, today, to fix it.

See http://www.strahlen.org/map/mapweathertest.htm

Could someone please check what I'm doing wrong? Or is this a bug outside of my influence?

Cheers! Frank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've included the maps-API 3 times.(you should receive a console-warning for that)

This is sufficient to include the API and both libraries(places+weather):

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=weather,places"></script>
```

The autocomplete will work too after the modification.

Comment: Just perfect..... I cannot remember that I was ever helped this fast and good. Thanks! I hope I can do something back on this support forum for other members.

Comment: Corrected version is online http://www.strahlen.org/map/mapweather.htm ; thanks again :)

Comment: To prevent link-rot: the final link in which I embedded this code is here http://www.strahlen.org/map/

Answer (score 0):

I am in a class that is creating a mobile map of our campus. We are using Fusion Tables, and Google Maps.  What intrigued me was how you incorporated the check boxes for Active/ old mine Active/ old quarry Dump Natural outcrop Museum Collector Shop/Dealer Club Fair Lab Other.  How did you do that? Are each of those layers using .kml, or did you just use one Fusion table, and had a column that was "type" with each of those where given an "id"?

What we are thinking of having visible on the map all of the buildings, but adding emergency box locations, OneCard locations, and perhaps vending machines.  How might we implement what you have done on our map?

Don

Currently this is the demo page:
[Fitchburg State University Mobile Demo](http://nolimitssocialmedia.comoj.com/interactivemap/mobilepage.html)

Comment: Hi Don, I'm happy that finally I can help someone instead of other people constantly helping me ;) No, it's only one FusionTables layer. No kml involved. The html code, in my case, simply reads the FusionTable and filters the column "title" for the exact text for the checkbox. Ergo: it filters the column "title" for all records with the string "Active mine", and puts the markers on the map.

Comment: The html code is so simple that you can copy/paste it, and then the FusionTables logic will do the intelligence. Create a FusionTables, create your columns (with the data for the InfoWindows), create a column for the filter (emergency, onecard, vending, etc), copy/paste my code and replace "active mine" etc for your selection criteria, and let it run. If you have more questions, please ask, but don't expect daily answers because we have a week-old baby here in the house ;) Cheers!